# Installing Python Package to Conda Env Without Using Conda

Tags: anaconda, conda, mysql-connector-python

I have a fresh Anaconda environment in which I would like to install the latest release of [mysql-connector-python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/) (v2.1.3). I'm on a CentOS6 system. The problem is, the newest Conda-hosted package is 2.0.3 and because the connector is not currently hosted on PyPI, it cannot be installed via Pip. (Pip's `--allow-external` option has been deprecated.)

I know that I can easily install the package via `yum install`, but I believe that will install it outside of the Conda environment.
Is there any way, using `yum` or otherwise, to isolate this package solely to this particular Conda environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is surprisingly simple. Just download the source for the Python package that is not available on PyPI and `pip install` at the source directory. Just remember to have the Conda environment you want to install to active and Pip will correctly isolate the install to env scope.

I was unaware of Pip's install from local options, so big thanks to the folks on the [Anaconda mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/-jQ7wZ9hDp0) for their help with this.